# Copied Arch not shown in EFI

Tags: arch-linux, grub, fstab

I tried to copy the entire arch install onto another hard drive (form HDD [/dev/sda] to SSD [/dev/sdb], both internal).

This is how I tried to do it:

- Live Arch stick
- mounted both root partitions
- cp -a /mnt/HDD/* /mnt/SSD
- same for boot and efi partition
- chrooted into SSD
- reinstalled grub
- run `grub-install`
- updated `/etc/fstab`

Everything seemed to work, but the SSD system is not displayed in my computer's EFI. What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT:

@Paul H.'s way to install grub now worked!

The only problem is that both EFI entries boot the same OS, which is the old (HDD, /dev/sda4) one...

Comment: How did you create the efi partition on the new drive? Was it formatted FAT32? And what options did you run grub-install with?

Comment: @PaulH. Yes. I created a 500 MB partition using fdisk, fomatted it as EFI partition and run `mkfs.fat /dev/sdb3`. The file system should be correct, as it displays it as vfat when running `genfstab`

Comment: @PaulH. and I run grub-install without any options, and it told me that it was a `x86_64-efi` install.

Comment: You could try installing grub with the options [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2).

Comment: @PaulH. I ran `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/dev/sdb3 --bootloader-id=arch_grub` and got `grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/sdb3'.`

Comment: @PaulH. Update: Sorry, i just replaced `/dev/sdb3` with `/boot/efi` and got the reply that I have to mount /dev. brb

Comment: okay, now i always get `device node not found`

Comment: I haven't encountered that  myself. Just to be sure, you mounted `/dev/sdb3` in `/boot/efi` and not just `/boot`, correct?

Comment: Yes. I am sure about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75300/discussion-between-paul-h-and-alexander-schoch).

Comment: Good Idea. But I've never done that. How do I get to the chatroom?

Comment: Go to here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413521/how-to-migrate-partitions-and-file-systems-to-another-device Instructions you need are at the bottom in the GRUB section. This also goes into detail about how to do this sort of thing fast but since you already copied everything just skip that.

Comment: @jdwolf Thank you. But the problem has already been solved... I'm just waiting for an answer to be written in order to mark it as solved.